# Error filling data into Dictionary in Method during second call

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

i call a method to send data to a webservice, but when i call it a second time, with a different value in a parameter i get an error.

```
let userdefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var params:Dictionary<String,String> = Dictionary()

override init() {
    var league_id = userdefault.valueForKeyPath("userdata.User.active_league") as Int
    var hash = userdefault.valueForKeyPath("userdata.encrypted") as String
    var token = userdefault.valueForKeyPath("userdata.token") as String

    params = ["token": token, "hash": hash, "league_id": String(league_id)]
}

func switchleague(active_league: Int) -> Bool {
    var switched = false
    var url = "switchleague"
    var user_id = userdefault.valueForKeyPath("userdata.User.id") as Int
// following error is shown to the code line below
// Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)
    params.updateValue(String(active_league), forKey: "active_league") 
    params.updateValue(String(user_id), forKey: "user_id")
    var resp:AnyObject = conn.postArrayToUrl(base + url, params: params)
    switched = resp.valueForKey("success") as Bool
    if(switched == true) {
        var league_id = resp.valueForKey("active_league") as Int
        userdefault.setObject(league_id, forKey: "userdata.User.active_league")
        userdefault.synchronize()
    }
    return switched
}
```

i do pretty much the same in a different method and have no problems with that.
Any idea on that?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but you don't have an ```active_league``` key in your dictionary, so how do you spec to update a key that doesn't exist?

Comment: manual says: if key does not exist it will be created. that part is working fine in the first call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved using NSMutableDictionary instead of native swift dictionary

Comment: Switching to NSMutableDictionary solved the problem. Thanks :)